# If $G$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$ then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$ as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

> If $G$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$ then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is linear over
>   $\mathbb{Z}$ as well?

We have $G \cong H \leq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ for some $n$ (this is what I mean when I say that $G$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$)

Then is $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong N \leq GL(n^2, \mathbb{Z})$?

---

I need this in context of:

> $G$ polycyclic, $\Gamma \leq \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ solvable $\implies \Gamma$
>   polycyclic

If the topic assertion is correct then this can proven as:

Every polycyclic group is linear of $\mathbb{Z}$, and every solvable linear group of $\mathbb{Z}$ is polycyclic.

Comment: What does " being linear over $\;\Bbb Z\;$" mean, anyway?

Comment: @DonAntonio We're using it as saying that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ for some $n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, because all free groups $F_n$ of finite rank are linear  over ${\mathbb Z}$, but it is proved [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82401887.pdf) that ${\rm Aut}(F_n)$ is not linear (over any field) for $n \ge 3$.

It is proved in Chapter 2 of Dan Segal's book on polycyclic groups that solvable subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ are polycyclic.

Comment: would you mind checking out my new question; its related to the one here and I will appreciate your guidance there:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012808/for-a-a-free-abelian-normal-subgroup-and-k-with-unipotent-image-c-ak